# TV show or movie with aliens taking people over via red triangles on their foreheads

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

I remember as a kid in the 1990s or early 2000s watching a VHS tape of a show or a movie (not quite sure which) but all I can really remember about it, which should be pretty major, was there were little green alien like things (and I mean like alien from the 1979 movie) but they were small and they would touch their heads to the main characters' heads and I guess enter their being through a red triangle on the human's forehead and take over their body. It's an animated series. If someone could figure it out I would REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but could it be 'The Head', an MTV Liquid Television series? It had both good and evil aliens riding around in the head of the protagonist and antagonists. Don't recall any triangles though. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aUKm5Rr7r8

Answer (score 7):

It's ***[Wild C.A.T.S](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251515/)*** (1994–1995) and it was not red but a yellow triangle upside down on the main protagonists' heads in the first episode.

> Universal war wages between two prehistoric alien races. One of the races is the heroic Kherubim while the other is the evil Daemonites.

You can view the relevant scenes at around the 11:19 and 14:24 marks in the video below.

Comment: You can accept your own answer latera and please do so.

Comment: You will need to [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) before being able to accept this answer